# Capturing the digit in a new line after whitespace

Tags: regex

The string we have right now is:
DB GOALS:   DISADVANTAGED BUSINESS ENTERPRISE -  6.0%
PROPOSALS ISSUED    9    FUND TOTAL         ,      ,                  0
TOTAL NUMBER OF WORKING DAYS     30

```
NUMBER OF BIDDERS  4   ENGINEERS EST      1,674,885.00  AMOUNT OVER
 177,014.00         PERCENT OVER EST 10.57
PROGRAM ELEMENTS
```

I am using the pattern `(AMOUNT OVER|AMOUNT UNDER)[\n\r\s]+(?:^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[0-9])?)(?!\S)` but it does not capture

```
AMOUNT OVER
 177,014.00
```

in the text. I suspect it is because of the whitespace before 177,014.00 because it works when we remove the whitespace.

Is there a way to capture it as it is? Thanks so much!

Here is the [regex101.com link](https://regex101.com/r/qVkYw7/1) for reference.

Comment: I was able to get your regex to work as-is by changing the options from multi-line to single-line (because you're handling your newlines yourself). Otherwise, the regex seems maybe a little overcomplicated. Might be because you were trying a bunch of different things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simplify the pattern a bit to:

```
\b(AMOUNT (?:OVER|UNDER))\s+((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?))(?!\S)
```

Note that `[\n\r\s]+` can be written as `\s+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ467P/1)